# Linkedin API is asking for member ID

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, linkedin-api

I am making an app in iOS that will allow user to login via linkedin.

I am using this console for linked api check https://apigee.com/console/linkedin

In "Get Member Profile" API I can not find which member id to provide.

I am getting a url in "Get My Profile" api call, in that url I'm getting an ID, I tried with that but its giving "Invalid member id" error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "Get My Connections" you'll get the list of your connections.From there between   tags you'll get member id associated with each of your connection.Give this as parameter and check.

provide url like this http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,maiden-name,picture-url,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,summary,location:(name,country:(code)),industry,distance,num-recommenders,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,specialties,date-of-birth,main-address,positions,email-address,educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))

to get all the profile information

Hope it helps

Comment: It is giving same result as "Get My Profile". But It gives data of particular user for whom I choose id. I want my details. can you please tell me that how can I get my other profile details including profile picture, Email address n all?

Comment: for your details go for "Get My Profile" on top of the list

Comment: on in "Get Member Profile" Only give url like this `http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~` it will work

Comment: Yah I did it but in that it provides only First name, Last Name, headline and profile url.

Comment: give url like this 'http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,maiden-name,picture-url,formatted-name,phonetic-last-name,summary,location:(name,country:(code)),industry,distance,num-recommenders,current-status,current-share,network,skills,phone-numbers,specialties,date-of-birth,main-address,positions,email-address,educations:(school-name,field-of-study,start-date,end-date,degree,activities))' it will give all the information of your's

Comment: I am glad it helped you.Thank you for up voting and accepting